# How to clear cache of static site on S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-s3

Ok, I got a static site hosted on S3 which is in fact an Angular App. I use the gulp module S3 upload to upload all my files to S3.

The problem I'm having is that the files seems to be uploaded ok, however when I visit the site, it looks like is serving an older version of the files and NOT the recently uploaded files. I've tried deleting all files from the bucket and upload again, yet the old file is still served on the site. If I download the file, I can see that the file in the bucket it is indeed the right file, but just doesn't get served.

I'm not using Cloudfront for this particular bucket. Do I need to? Or is there a way to clear the cache?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: your browser would have cached it and it is not downloading anything from S3. What happens when you delete files from s3, does your angular app works? It will work if browser has cached the JS files. While I am not using S3, but in my react app, the generated JS file has a random name so that when browser downloads index.html, it gets the link to new JS file and the cached js is not used.

Comment: When I delete the files from S3, the app stops working. When I upload the files again, it serves the older files, even though the js and css files have timestamp on it. I'm also using Chrome on incognito mode. What I've noticed however is that if I wait a few minutes, the deployment does appear. It seems it takes a while to deploy?

Comment: yes, i have seen the lag too, but that is when accessing buckets across regions. I upload my build to a bucket in us-west-2 and my ec2 instance is in us-west-1. I generally wait for 5-10 mins before spawning ec2 in us-west-1 which picks the build and runs it. This is a demo setup.

Comment: Either use cache busting param as @dy10 advises or set a correct cache-control header on the files so they are always revalidated.

Comment: *"When I delete the files from S3, the app stops working. When I upload the files again, it serves the older files, even though the js and css files have timestamp on it."* You realize, I'm sure, how improbable that sounds. The most likely explanation for that would be a transient problem in S3, but when you overwrite an object, you're not really overwriting the object in storage, even without versioning enabled (you're overwriting the index)... so delete => 404 => upload => get old object should be almost impossible.  Have you cross-verified this behavior by downloading the files with `curl`?

Answer (score -3):

These are a bunch of excuses. This is a caching issue. The issue is that Amazon s3 services have a poorly designed interface, so you need to 'invalidate' the pages, which is a long garbage process, compared to most the competitors who just have a simple clear cache button. Very BAD design by Amazon!